# Why I am getting this parse error message while connecting to mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

I am learning php and mysql using php and mysql for dummies book. When I am trying to run this code given in the book, I am getting error message.:

Parse error: parse error in `C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_test.php` on line 6

I also tried making a registration page of a website using php but it's not working, and if i use `mysql_error()` then i get an output that there is a parse error.

What is this parse error? How can i fix it?

```
<?php
/* Program: mysql_test.php
* Desc: Connects to MySQL Server and
* outputs settings.
*/
echo “<html>
<head><title>Test MySQL</title></head>
<body>”;
$host = “localhost”;
$user = “root”;
$password = “hello”;
$cxn = mysqli_connect($host,$user,$password);
$sql=”SHOW DATABASES”;
$result = mysqli_query($cxn,$sql);
if($result == false)
{
echo “<h4>Error: “.mysqli_error($cxn).”</h4>”;
}
else
{
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) < 1)
{
echo “<p>No current databases</p>”;
}
else
{
echo “<ol>”;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result))
{
echo “<li>$row[0]</li>”;
}
echo “</ol>”;
}
}
?>
</body></html>
```

Comment: Paste your code here...

Comment: Yeah and check your 6th line.

Comment: Check you PHP code. This is not a MySQL error message (it is a PHP one). Check that all semicolons `;`, pharentesis are in place (near the 6th line of your code). It could be that the root of the error message is in the 5th or 4th line (just the parser reports the error later).

Comment: I am failing to format the code for pasting. However, does 6th line means the 6th line including comments or it excludes comments and refers to the 6th line of the main code?

Comment: Please paste the first 6 lines of the C:\xampp\htdocs\mysql_test.php file

Comment: I can't format it for any reason :(

Comment: Paste it, then highlight the code, then press CTRL+K. Please be sure that there is at least one empty line before and after your code (it should be a separate paragraph. *BUT*! Please note that StackOverflow is not a code dubigging service. With or without the code, this question is considered as a low quality and off-topic. For more information please read [ask]

Answer (score 0):

You have 'bad' quotes. What text editor you used? Whatever, just replace all

```
“
```

quotes with with these quotes

```
"
```

here they are side by side to see the difference

```
“ "
```

These decoration quotes have unicode code of #e2809c while normal quotes should have #22

Comment: try it. If it was not you text editor then it was your keyboard layout or something that writes decoration quotes(unicode#e2809c) instead of normal quotes (UNICODE#22)